# More efficient way to update multiple model objects each with unique values

Tags: python, django, sql-update

I am looking for a more efficient way to update a bunch of model objects. Every night I have background jobs creating 'NCAABGame' objects from an API once the scores are final.

In the morning I have to update all the fields in the model with the stats that the API did not provide.

As of right now I get the stats formatted from an excel file and I copy and paste each update and run it like this:

```py
    NCAABGame.objects.filter(
        name__name='San Francisco', updated=False).update(
        field_goals=38,
        field_goal_attempts=55,
        three_points=11,
        three_point_attempts=24,
        ...
    )
```

The other day there were 183 games, most days between 20-30 so it can be very timely doing it this way. I've looked into bulk_update and a few other things but I can't really find a solution. I'm sure there is something simple that I'm just not seeing.

I appreciate any ideas or solutions you can offer.

Comment: load the excel file as csv and then loop through each column/row using your current method or just update with the api data directly instead of saving it in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update each object that gets created via the API manually anyway, I would not even bother going through Django. Just load your games from the API directly in Excel, then make your edits in Excel, and save as CSV file. Then I would add the CSV directly into the database table, unless there is a specific reason that objects must be created via Django? I mean, you can of course do that with something like the below, which could be modified to also work for your current method via updates, but then you need to first retrieve the correct pk of the object that you want to update.

```
import csv
  
with open("my_data.csv", 'r') as my_data_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_data_file) 
    for row in reader:

        # get_or_create returns a tuple. 'created' is a boolean that indicates
        # if a new object was created or not, with game holding the object that
        # was either retrieved or created

        game, created = NCAABGame.objects.get_or_create(
            name=row[0],
            field_goals=row[1],
            field_goal_attempts=row[2],
            ....,
            )
```

Comment: The API provides betting lines to display as they progress throughout the week. So the initial game objects are created and constantly updated days before the game actually happens. 

The API just doesn’t provide game stats so I need to add them after the game is final.

Comment: @ryan_thomas You can easily adapt it to suit your needs. Just use your original way of updating filtering on name and updated, but using csv from excel. You could also display your games in the admin interface tabular and edit the values directly there instead of excel.